# Onload click the link

Tags: javascript, jquery

At the moment the following code will load only when the users clicks the link.

I want on load of the page this to happen without the user having to click.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Support for AJAX loaded modal window
    $(document).on('click', '.btn-modal', function() {
        $.get($(this).attr('data-target'), function(data) {
            $('#modal').html(data);
            $('#modal').modal('show');
        }, 'html');
    });
});​
</script>

<!-- Modal window to load dynamic content -->

<div class="modal hide fade customDialog" id="modal"></div>
<a class="btn btn-modal" data-target="page.html" >Launch Modal</a>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery how to trigger click?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158532/jquery-how-to-trigger-click)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

        // Support for AJAX loaded modal window
        $(document).on('click','.btn-modal',function() {

            $.get($(this).attr('data-target'), function(data) {
             $('#modal').html(data);
             $('#modal').modal('show');
           }, 'html');
       });

      // here write
      $('.btn-modal').click();
     // if you have multiple button then keep filter
     // eg.
     // $('.btn-modal:eq(0)').click(); // for first button
     // $('.btn-modal:eq(1)').click(); // for second button and so more
 });
```

Comment: Although the click event handler is bound to the document, it won't be triggered by that, since this is event delegation.

Comment: This is dangerous if there are multiple `.btn-modal` elements, as the code will run once for each of them.  I would suggest changing `$('.btn-modal').click();` to `$('.btn-modal:first').click();`, as in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just add this to the end of your `$(document).ready()` handler:

```
$('.btn-modal:first').click();
```